# How to add leading zero to time using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

In the code below, I'm using the current date and time, with the help of which I am generating a file name. My problem is that it's giving me an output without leading zeros:

```
Dim strDateTime As String = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() & "" & _ 
DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() & "" & DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() & "" & _ 
DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() & "" & DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() & "" & _
DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() & DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()
```

For example, my query is giving output as below currently:

Assume time is `1:5:30  :: hh:mm:ss`

Required output is: `01:05:30`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00") & ":" & DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00") & ":" & DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("00")
```

**EDIT :**

As suggested by 'mdb' in the answers, using [Custom Date and Time Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) Strings would be more efficient and cleaner

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt") '12 Hour format with AM/PM designator, Eg :- 09:01:01 PM
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") '24 Hour format  Eg :- 21:01:01
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of concatenating strings, which is highly inefficient, you'll want to use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). This also supports [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), which make it trivial to achieve what you want.